# Win 2016 server - Docker experimental does not work

Tags: powershell, troubleshooting, docker-for-windows

I've installed Windows 2016 server (on Vsphere with VMware tools and Hyper-V enabled) and Docker for running Windows Containers.
I opened powershell with administrator privileges and ran this command:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
```

but i got this response:

```
ltsc2019: Pulling from windows/servercore no matching manifest for
unknown in the manifest list entries
```

I've searched how to troubleshoot it and the suggestions say to enable experimental environment. Then I enabled it through GUI and check it via powershell:

```
docker version -f '{{.Server.Experimental}}'
true
```

but if I try to inspect the image:

```
docker manifest inspect -v mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
```

I get this:

```
docker manifest inspect is only supported on a Docker cli with experimental cli features enabled
```

I tried also Linux containers mode and this works.

How can I run this image?

Comment: I don't know if it's this problem in particular, but you won't be able to run Server 2019 containers in a Server 2016 host environment. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility for details.